# Automatically Reload a File in LISP When a Command Is Entered

Tags: lisp

I'm learning LISP for a class. I have a basic workflow setup in Ubuntu with my LISP file in VIM and an interactive LISP prompt in a terminal that I'm using to test code as I write it. Is there a way to get LISP to load a specific file every time I type a command? It's getting a bit tiring having to constantly input `(load 'initial-code.cl)` (yes, even when I am using the  terminal's history).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can always try:

```
(let (fn)
  (defun l (&optional filename)
    (if filename
      (setf fn filename))
    (load fn)))
```

Works like this:

```
[2]> (l "x.lisp")
;; Loading file x.lisp ...
;; Loaded file x.lisp
T
[3]> (l)
;; Loading file x.lisp ...
;; Loaded file x.lisp
T
[4]>
```

Pretty simple.

You can also do something like:

```
(defun go ()
  (load "project.lisp")
  (yourfunc 'your 'parameters))
```

Then you just type (go) and it reloads your file and calls your main entry point.

Or even combine them:

```
(defun gogo (&rest args)
    (l) ;; call (l "file.lisp") first to initialize it
    (apply #'yourfunc args))
```

then you can change your parameters easily

```
(gogo 1 2)
(gogo 2 4)
```

Ya know, it's lisp. Don't like something, change it.

With more time, you can write a simple wrapper that can build these on the fly. But you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Most Lisp programmers would encourage you to use [SLIME](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/).

If you like Eclipse, there is also a [Lisp plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dandelion-ecl/).

I know this doesn't really answer your question, but at least you can be aware of some alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [slimv](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2531), it is like slime for vim.